# Check what procedure modified data in IBM Netezza

Tags: netezza

I found that Netezza stores history of data in HISDB schema. Is it possible to join them so I would get history of which table has been modified by what procedure?

Reason for this is I have DataStage job that loads Netezza table and after SQL command triggers procedures that add another set of data to that same table. I am in need to have all events documented for data lineage purpose.

Current query I made returns procedure's call time. Issue is with joining to `USER_HISTDB."$hist_table_access_3"`. The only field that matched is `NPSINSTANCEID`. `LOGENTRYID`, `OPID` and `SESSIONID` have different value.

That stops me from making procedure to table link.

```
SELECT 
b.SUBMITTIME,
b.QUERYTEXT,
b.USERNAME,
b.DBNAME,
b.SCHEMANAME,
a.*
FROM USER_HISTDB."$hist_log_entry_3" a
JOIN USER_HISTDB."$hist_query_prolog_3" b
ON a.LOGENTRYID = b.LOGENTRYID
AND a.SESSIONID = b.SESSIONID 
AND a.NPSID = b.NPSID
AND a.NPSINSTANCEID = b.NPSINSTANCEID

WHERE b.QUERYTEXT like '%PROCEDURE_NAME%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- By default, information about stored procedures is not logged
-- in the query history database. To enable logging of such ...
set ENABLE_SPROC_HIST_LOGGING = on;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- TABLE -- All Info About All Accesses
-- ====================================

SELECT

    QP.submittime,
    substr(QP.querytext, 1, 100) as  SQL_STATEMENT,
    xid,                             --  the transaction id (which might be either a CREATEXID or DELETEXID)
    username,

    CASE
        when usage =   1 then  'SELECTED'
        when usage =   2 then  'INSERTED'
        when usage =   3 then  'SELECTED/INSERTED'
        when usage =   4 then  'DELETED'
        when usage =   5 then  'SELECTED/DELETED'
        when usage =   8 then  'UPDATED'
        when usage =   9 then  'SELECTED/UPDATED'
        when usage =  16 then  'TRUNCATED'
        when usage =  32 then  'DROPPED'
        when usage =  64 then  'CREATED'
        when usage = 128 then  'GENSTATS'
        when usage = 256 then  'LOCKED'
        when usage = 512 then  'ALTERED'
                         else  'other'
    END AS OPERATION,

    TA.dbname,
    TA.schemaname,
    TA.tablename,
    TA.tableid,
    PP.planid       -- The MAIN query plan (not all table operations involve a query plan)

    -- If you want to see EVERYTHING, uncomment the next line.
    -- Or pick and choose the columns you want to see.
    --    ,*

FROM

    ---- SESSION information
                     "$hist_session_prolog_3"  SP
    left outer join  "$hist_session_epilog_3"  SE  using ( SESSIONID, npsid, npsinstanceid )

    ---- QUERY information (to include the SQL statement that was issued)
    left outer join  "$hist_query_prolog_3"    QP  using ( SESSIONID, npsid, npsinstanceid )
    left outer join  "$hist_query_epilog_3"    QE  using ( OPID,      npsid, npsinstanceid )

    left outer join  "$hist_table_access_3"    TA  using ( OPID,      npsid, npsinstanceid )

    ---- PLAN information
    ---- Not all queries result in a query plan (for example, TRUNCATE and DROP do not)
    ---- And some queries might result in multiple query plans (such as a GROOM statement)
    ---- By including these joins we might get multiple rows (for any given row in the $hist_table_access_3 table)
    left outer join  "$hist_plan_prolog_3"   PP  using ( OPID,      npsid, npsinstanceid )
    left outer join  "$hist_plan_epilog_3"   PE  using ( PLANID,    npsid, npsinstanceid )

WHERE

    (ISMAINPLAN isnull or ISMAINPLAN = true)
     ---- So ...
     ---- If there is NO plan file (as with a truncate) ... then ISMAINPLAN will be null.  Include this row.
     ---- If there is a plan file, include ONLY the record corresponding to the MAIN plan file.
     ---- (Otherwise, there could end up being a lot of duplicated information).

     and TA.tableid > 200000
     ---- Ignore access information for SYSTEM tables (where the OBJID # < 200000)

----
----Add any other restrictions here (otherwise, this query as written will return a lot of data)
----

ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Nice one Mark :)

Comment: Strange thing I've noticed. I queried table that ws modified lately using `CreateXid` attribute and used that number as `PP.XID = <number_indicated_by_previous_query>`. It returned actions from 2 years back. Should I used in that case `NPSID = 
AND NPSINSTANCEID = 
AND OPID = 
AND LOGENTRYID = 
AND SESSIONID = 
AND USERID = 459` as filters on hist_query_prolog_3 to get current modifications?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction ID is unique for each execution of a given statement and its visible on the record in the table (hidden columns called CreateXid and DeleteXid). That same ID can be found on the HISTDB tables.

Do you need help with a query against those tables ?

Comment: Yes, I try to query these table but joins don't seem to be workig.

Comment: I added current query I have.